# Training a image classifier with over 300k classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, resnet

Is it possible to train a image classifier network with over an enormous number of classes? (say 300k classes), with each class having a minimum of 10 images split up between train/test/validation (ie. >3mil 250x250x3 images).

I have tried to train the dataset using the ResNet50 model and decreasing the batch size to as low as 1, but still have been running into OOM issues (2080 Ti). I have found out that the OOM is caused by having too many parameters and ergo I have resorted to trying to train the network on an extremely basic 10-layer model with a batch size of 1. It runs, but, the speed/accuracy is  unsurprisingly abysmal.

Is there anyway I can maybe divide the training sets into smaller sections of classes, such that:

1st .h5 = classes 1 ~ 20,000

2nd .h5 = classes 20,001 ~ 40,000

3rd .h5 = classes 40,001 ~ 60,000, etc.

and later merging into a single h5 file that can be loaded to recognize all 300k different classes?

---

EDIT PER ASHISH'S SUGGESTION:

I have (I think) successfully merged 2 models into one, but the merged model has somewhat doubled in the number of layers...

Source code:

```
model1 = load_model('001.h5')
model2 = load_model('002.h5')

for layer in model1.layers:
    layer._name = layer._name + "_1" # avoid duplicate layer names, which would otherwise throw an error
    layer.trainable = False

for layer in model2.layers:
    layer._name = layer._name + "_2"
    layer.trainable = False

x1 = model1.layers[-1].output
classes = x1.shape[1]
x1 = Dense(classes, activation='relu', name='out1')(x1)

x2 = model2.layers[-1].output
x2 = Dense(x2.shape[1], activation='relu', name='out2')(x2)
classes += x2.shape[1]

x = concatenate([x1, x2])
output_layer = Dense(classes, activation='softmax', name='combined_layer')(x)
new_model = Model(inputs=[model1.inputs, model2.inputs], outputs=output_layer)
new_model.summary()
new_model.save('new_model.h5', overwrite=True)
```

And the resulting model looks like this:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
=========================================================================
input_1_1 (InputLayer)          [(None, 224, 224, 3) 0                                            
_________________________________________________________________________
input_1_2 (InputLayer)          [(None, 224, 224, 3) 0                                            
_________________________________________________________________________
conv1_pad_1 (ZeroPadding2D)     (None, 230, 230, 3)  0           input_1_1[0][0]                  
_________________________________________________________________________
conv1_pad_2 (ZeroPadding2D)     (None, 230, 230, 3)  0           input_1_2[0][0]                  
_________________________________________________________________________
conv1_conv_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 112, 112, 64) 9472        conv1_pad_1[0][0]                
_________________________________________________________________________
conv1_conv_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 112, 112, 64) 9472        conv1_pad_2[0][0]                

...

...

conv5_block3_out_1 (Activation) (None, 7, 7, 2048)   0           conv5_block3_add_1[0][0]         
_________________________________________________________________________
conv5_block3_out_2 (Activation) (None, 7, 7, 2048)   0           conv5_block3_add_2[0][0]         
_________________________________________________________________________
avg_pool_1 (GlobalAveragePoolin (None, 2048)         0           conv5_block3_out_1[0][0]         
_________________________________________________________________________
avg_pool_2 (GlobalAveragePoolin (None, 2048)         0           conv5_block3_out_2[0][0]         
_________________________________________________________________________
probs_1 (Dense)                 (None, 953)          1952697     avg_pool_1[0][0]                 
_________________________________________________________________________
probs_2 (Dense)                 (None, 3891)         7972659     avg_pool_2[0][0]                 
_________________________________________________________________________
out1 (Dense)                    (None, 953)          909162      probs_1[0][0]                    
_________________________________________________________________________
out2 (Dense)                    (None, 3891)         15143772    probs_2[0][0]                    
_________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 4844)         0           out1[0][0]                       
                                                                 out2[0][0]                       
_________________________________________________________________________
combined_layer (Dense)          (None, 4844)         23469180    concatenate[0][0]                
=========================================================================
Total params: 96,622,894
Trainable params: 39,522,114
Non-trainable params: 57,100,780
```

As you can see, all the layers have been doubled due to Model(inputs=[input1, input2]). That will cause problems for me later when I want to use this model to predict images. Is there anyway I can do this without doubling all the previous layers and just add the trailing dense layers? At this rate I'll be overloaded with the number of parameters even faster than before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

technically it's possible, So what you can do is since you have 3 classifiers(1.h5,2.h5,3.h5), you can load these model with their weights and then use functional API in tensorflow https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional where concatenate() API will combine output of the 3 classifiers to single vector and then use few dense network with activation function to make the final prediction.

Comment: Adding to this, you could use a simple attention mechanism to indicate which of the 3 classifiers manages the relevant classification.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on that please? Thanks